# Validation for TextField of Type Number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik

I am using this text field:

```
 <TextField
    variant="outlined"
    margin="normal"
    id="freeSeats"
    name="freeSeats"
    helperText={touched.freeSeats ? errors.freeSeats : ''}
    error={touched.freeSeats && Boolean(errors.freeSeats)}
    label="Free Seats"
    value={freeSeats}
    onChange={change.bind(null, 'freeSeats')}
  />
```

with this validation:

```
export const schema = Yup.object({
  freeSeats: Yup.number()
    .required('This Field is Required')
    .typeError('A Number is Required'),
});
```

It works well and shows an error when I am entering the alphabets. However, when I add

```
type="number"
```

inside the text field, the arrows to increase/decrease the numerical value show up but the validation is no longer working. So even if I write an alphabet, it doesn't give me an error. and if I move to another text field after typing alphabets, the input just overlaps with the label as if there was no input at all.

Is there any way I can keep the material UI number type arrows along with the validation?

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-wind-zwh6i?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/

Comment: Can you post your code to codesandbox.io and give me a link here?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-wind-zwh6i?file=/src/App.tsx @rzwnahmd

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening underneath.

- `<input type="number">` is **lowest level of `validation`** on that field at DOM API level.
  So browsers handle this by adding those small arrows to signal that only `numbers` are expected. Browser won't complain when you enter any `letters` but silently they won't take that `value`.
- So to improve that behavior, most libraries came up with **high level `validation`**.
  That's where `Yup` and many form packages comes into the picture.

> That conflicting behavior is because DOM "silent low-level" validation sort of over-rules your `Yup` "higher level" validation.

Actaully, on browsers that don't support `type="number"`, that input falls back to `type="text"`.
[Here's on a good read on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

Comment: I am using Material UI's TextField. I don't think there's a NumberField. Is there?

Comment: My bad, I updated the explanation to just cover what you used.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, it works fine. User isn't able to type letters in the input just the numbers and the required field validation also works fine:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-goodall-wgw2w

Comment: Could you describe what you changed? Because if I open the link, the issue is the same as before. Maybe you didn't save?

Comment: Yes my bad, have a look now. I've commented out the line where you were calling `formik.handleBlur(props)`. Let me know if it solved your problem or not :)

Comment: Nope, it overlaps with the label and the 'type error' is not shown either. The behaviour of the text type field (which I added just now) is different.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot help you if the code you've provided doesn't replicate the actual scenario.

Comment: It represents the actual scenario but maybe my question isn't very clear. Thanks anyway. I'll just use the text type for now

Comment: No problem, have one last look at the link I gave you. I've made some changes, now there are two fields. But the label doesn't overlap when the input is blurred.

Comment: Type some text into the textfield and then click outside in the white area. You'll see it overlaps